# How can this be proven (Matrices)

Tags: matrices

I need to prove why the image on the bottom is true, btw this is on a matrices unit so you know that the order of multiplication does matter
[the math problem http://www.imagesup.net/di-2142481773316.png](http://www.imagesup.net/di-2142481773316.png)

Comment: Hint: $Y(\alpha A^2 +\beta A +\gamma I)Y^{-1}=0$ if and only if  $(\alpha A^2 +\beta A +\gamma I)=0$. Compute $A^2$ and see what you get (in terms of $X,Y,Y^{-1}).$

Comment: More generally, any equation involving scalars, $n \times n$ matrices, addition and multiplication remains true when each matrix $X$ is replaced by $Y^{-1} X Y$, where $Y$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix.  This is because $X \to Y^{-1} X Y$ is an automorphism of the algebra of $n \times n$ matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A = Y^{-1}XY$, $A^2 = (Y^{-1}XY)(Y^{-1}XY) = Y^{-1}X^2 Y$. So

$$\alpha A^2 + \beta A + \gamma I = Y^{-1}(\alpha X^2 + \beta X + \gamma I)Y  = Y^{-1}0Y = 0.$$

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i don't totally understand it, why would αA^2+βA+γI equal Y*−1(αX2+βX+γI)Y, and why would (Y^−1XY)(Y*−1XY)=Y*−1X*2Y

Comment: @epelle it's because $$\alpha A^2 + \beta A + \gamma I = Y^{-1}(\alpha X^2)Y + Y^{-1}(\beta X)Y + Y^{-1}(\gamma I)Y = Y^{-1}(\alpha X^2 + \beta X + \gamma I)Y$$ Note the last step is obtained by the distributive property.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $A^2=A\cdot A=(Y^{-1}XY)(Y^{-1}XY)=Y^{-1}X^2Y$. Now multiply the left equation from the left by $Y^{-1}$ and from the right by $Y$, and your result follows.